# Who came up with 3/2 SV model

Tags: stochastic-volatility, reference-request, history

Sorry, not a very quantitative question, but does anybody know who was the first person to write down and publish the 3/2 stochastic volatility model? I need this for a reference/bibliography.

Comment: Lewis (2000, Option Valuation under Stochastic Volatility) claims authorship for the 3/2 model on page 54 pointing out that Heston (1997) derived the model independendly.

Comment: I have just looed some other papers which refer to Heston (1997) and Platen (1997, A Non-Linear Stochastic Volatility Model) as original source.

Comment: Thanks! yes I think Heston and Platen indeed.